# Apply this function to a 2D numpy Matrix vector operations only

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

guys, I have this function

```
def averageRating(a,b):
  avg = (float(a)+float(b))/2
  return round(avg/25)*25
```

Currently, I am looping over my np array which is just a 2D array that has numerical values. What I want to be able to do is have "a" be the 1st array and "b" be the 2nd array and get the average per row and what I want for my return is just an array with the values. I have used mean but could not find a way to edit it and have the round() part or multiple (avg*25)/25. 
My goal is to get rid of looping and replace it with a vectorized operations because of how slow looping is.
Sorry for the question new to python and numpy.

Comment: can you add an example to show the 2D array and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def averageRating(a,b):
    avg = (np.average(a,axis=1) + np.average(b,axis=1))/2
    return np.round(avg,0)
```

This should do what you are looking for if I understand the question correctly. Specifying axis = 1 in np.average will give the average of the rows (axis = 0 would be the average of the columns). And the 0 in np.round will round to 0 decimal places, changing it will change the number of decimal places you round to. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

def averageRating(a, b):

```
averages = []
for i in range( len(a) ):
    averages.append( (a[i] + b[i]) / 2 )

return averages
```

Giving your arrays are of equal length this should be a simple resolution.

This doesn't eliminate the use of for loops, however, it will be computationally cheaper than the current approach.